# Django admin cannot delete/change instances

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-admin

I am working on a Django project, and had registered all my models to admin. But due to some reason, I cannot change any of the instances of any model that I created.
This is how it shows:

[image: Initial Screen]

This is the initial screen as I log in.
As soon as I click on add/change, instead of the usual screen it shows like this:

[image: Second Screen]

Here are my models.py and admin.py:
admin.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Plant, Unit, Equipment, EquipmentCategories, Job, Task_category, Subtask_category, SubtaskStatus, TaskStatus, Files, Filetype, Comment, Timelog, Report, Approvals, Task_flow, Subtask_flow

# Register your models here.
admin.site.register(Plant)
admin.site.register(Unit)
admin.site.register(EquipmentCategories)
admin.site.register(Equipment)
admin.site.register(Job)
admin.site.register(Task_category)
admin.site.register(TaskStatus)
admin.site.register(Subtask_category)
admin.site.register(SubtaskStatus)
admin.site.register(Files)
```

models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
import django.dispatch

# Create your models here.
class Plant(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    start_date = models.DateField(null=True,blank=True)
    end_date = models.DateField(null=True,blank=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return(self.name)

class Unit(models.Model):
    plant = models.ForeignKey(Plant,related_name='Plant', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    unit_location = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    start_date = models.DateField(null=True,blank=True)
    end_date = models.DateField(null=True,blank=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return(self.name)

class EquipmentCategories(models.Model):
    unit = models.ForeignKey(Unit,related_name='Unit', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    def __str__(self):
        return(self.name)
```

Can anyone please help!
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Edit: In the second figure, nothing happens if I click on Add. Also the change option vanishes

Comment: Do you have some CSS framework that you've added to the admin? There is a button with two arrows on it just below "Home" `<<`, does clicking that shrink the nav?

Comment: Perhaps something is not right with permissions of the user that you are logged in with. Can you check whether you are a superuser? ("Users" link)

Comment: Yes I am a superuser

Comment: No I did not add any CSS. That  `<<` also came in automatically

Comment: The `>>` shrinks the model-names. The add option still remains, but is not clickable

Comment: I curious it .  Could you show more codes? From the pic you show ,you had get the `change` authority. Are you doing some DIY admin site development?If you are just code some demo,I think this error may  never come.

Comment: Have added the admin.py and models.py

Answer (score 0):

I think something is wrong with your STATIC_URL in your settings.py file.
That fixed the issue for me.
It's not finding the right path to your static/admin css and js files.

Answer (score 0):

This problem also occurs when you don't migrate your models properly in the terminal. Make sure to always migrate your models after having modified them.

Answer (score -1):

Will be an issue with your user permissions.

Open the command line and `cd /to/your/directory/with/manage.py` and run `python -m manage createsuperuser`

Once you've created that login with those details and you should be able to update things.

Comment: So as of now, I am a superuser in it